# Detect Spamtrap mail in my database

Tags: php, email, spam

I wonder how I could check if the email addresses of my database (forum) contains mail spamtrap.
I think first check if the domain exists:

```
$domain = substr($email, strpos($email, '@') + 1);
if  (checkdnsrr($domain) !== FALSE) {
    echo 'Domain is valid!';
}
```

but how can I check if the email account really exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically check if an email address exists *to an absolute certainty*. You can make educated guesses, through.

1) Probing: Find a mail exchanger for the target domain (DNS MX record), open an SMTP connection and probe the address using the `RCPT TO` SMTP command, then `QUIT` without actually sending the email. The SMTP response code you receive for RCPT TO will tell if the mailbox is available. This method has a pretty good success rate, but some servers will respond with *"Oh sure I like that recipient a lot"* if the domain is among the accepted relay domains, but the user does not exist. This is a typical issue with backup email servers that have no information on the actual users.

2) VRFY: Open an SMTP connection the same way as above, then use the SMTP `VRFY` command to check if the user exists. This is likely to fail, given that support for VRFY is often disabled.